# Lenovo Z580 Graphics Cards

Tags: windows-8, nvidia-geforce, integrated-graphics, intel-graphics

I recently purchased a laptop with an Intel Core i5-3210M running at 2.5 Gigahertz with 6 gigabytes of RAM with a maximum of 8 gigabytes of RAM. The laptop had windows 8 preinstalled. It only came with Intel HD 4000 integrated graphics, however, other configurations of this laptop with the same motherboard and processor come from the factory with a dedicated Nvidia Geforce card as well as integrated Intel graphics and use Nvidia Optimus technology to switch between graphics cards. I am wondering if i could add an Nvidia card in one of my three available PCI express slots and install the Nvidia Optimus driver. Currently in my "Bios" or whatever Windows 8 replaced it with, there are no options for Optimus. My question is if i added an Nvidia card and installed the Optimus driver, would it work? Also, should i install the driver first and then the card?

Comment: this is not possible. The GPUs are added to the motherboard. If you want a GPU, you must buy a laptop which has the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sort of. Generally there's only one PCI-E slot (maybe 2) and they're mini pci-e formfactor. No one that I know of makes video cards in that formfactor, and they're usually x1 slots anyway (most graphics cards run at x16, or x8).

There's a previous question that asked about [upgrading video cards](https://superuser.com/a/523487/10165), and the same answer might be true here - there might be some graphics adaptors that would work, and they're of the MXM formfactor, and its a crapshoot.

There's one more option though, assuming you're using this on a desk, you may be able to get a expresscard -> PCIe adaptor - you'd need to supply a power supply, and of course there's the cost of the kit itself. Notebook review has a [nice in depth guide on the process](http://forum.notebookreview.com/e-gpu-external-graphics-discussion/418851-diy-egpu-experiences.html)

Comment: I have an available PCI slot designated as a PEG Gen1/Gen2/Gen3 X16. Here is my speccy screenshot: http://i1289.photobucket.com/albums/b516/evane999/Capture_zps6cfce21e.png